# difference between `header = None` and `header = 0` in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I was writing a code to read a `csv` file using `pandas` and I saw some weird functioning of the package. My file has column names which I want to ignore, so I use `header = 0` or `'infer'` instead of `None`. But I see something weird.

When I use `None` and I want to get a specific column, I just need to do `df[column_index]` but when I use `0` or `'infer'`, I need to do `df.ix[:,column_index]` to get the column otherwise, for `df[column_index]` I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/sarvagya/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py",
>   line 2525, in get_loc
>       return self._engine.get_loc(key)   File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
>   "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 139, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
>   "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item   File
>   "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item KeyError: column_index
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/home/sarvagya/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py",
>   line 2139, in **getitem**
>       return self._getitem_column(key)   File "/home/sarvagya/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py",
>   line 2146, in _getitem_column
>       return self._get_item_cache(key)   File "/home/sarvagya/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py",
>   line 1842, in _get_item_cache
>       values = self._data.get(item)   File "/home/sarvagya/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py",
>   line 3843, in get
>       loc = self.items.get_loc(item)   File "/home/sarvagya/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py",
>   line 2527, in get_loc
>       return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))   File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 117, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
>   "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 139, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
>   "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item   File
>   "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item KeyError: column_index

Can someone help with this? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 7):

The difference pops up when working with a dataframe with header, so lets say your DataFrame `df` has header!

1. `header=None` pandas automatically assign the first row of `df` (which is the actual column names) to the first row, hence your columns no longer have names
2. `header=0`, pandas first deletes column names(header) and then assign new column names to them (only if you pass names = [........] while loading your file).
   `read_csv( filepath, header = 0 , names = ['....' , '....' ...])`

hope it helps!

Comment: i had to use `header=None` with `name=list(str)` to get it to stop deleting the first row

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have a csv file like this `student.csv` where you have the names of columns in first row.

```
    id class marks
0   01 10    97
1   02 9     85
2   03 11    70
```

and you want to read this csv file, you can do this -

```
df = pd.read_csv('student.csv')
```

or

```
df = pd.read_csv('student.csv', header=0)
```

these both statements will give the same format of csv file as above.

but if you try to use this -

```
df = pd.read_csv('student.csv', header=None)
```

pandas will assume that you don't have columns names in your file and will make it own and will print the csv file in this format.

```
    0   1    2
0   id class marks
1   01 10    97
2   02 9     85
3   03 11    70
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like need 2 parameters - `header=None` and `skiprows=1` if want ignore original columns names for default `RangeIndex`.

Because if use only `header=None` in first row get original columns names.

And `header=0` read first row to columns names of `DataFrame`.

**Sample**:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), header=0)
print (df)
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```

---

Selecting by position:

```
print (df.iloc[:, 1])
0    2
1    5
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

Selecting by column name:

```
print (df['b'])

0    2
1    5
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

There is no column name `1`, so:

> print (df[1])
>   KeyError: 1

---

```
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), header=None)
print (df)
   0  1  2
0  a  b  c
1  1  2  3
2  4  5  6

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), header=None, skiprows=1)
print (df)
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6

print (df[1])
0    2
1    5
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I know that I need to use `skiprows`. I don't understand why I'm getting the error

Comment: So in your code `df[1]` failed? Because keyerror means there is no column with `column_index`

Comment: that `column_index` is just for inference. There's actually an `int` value there, like `0` or `1`, so if it's `df[1]`, then keyError is `1`

Comment: Hmm, so in code is used `header=None` and `df[1]` or `df[0]` not working? It is really weird. But if use `header=0` it is expected, because csv header is converted to columns names.

Comment: No, it's the other way round, if `header=None` then `df[1]` works. But not with `header=0`

Comment: @SarvagyaGupta - Sorry, it cannot working, because if use `header=0` then there is no columns names `0,1...`. Then need `df.iloc[:,column_index]` for select by position. For columns `0,1...` need `header=None`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177694/discussion-between-sarvagya-gupta-and-jezrael).